# Why is vertical scrolling not working whereas horizontal scrolling is working in a webpage?

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage where there is a slider like this `https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/GooeyImageHoverEffects/`. The problem is that vertial scroling is not working when I use the mouse wheel, only horizontal scroll is working when I use the mouse wheel. The webpage has a plugin named HorizontalScrollPlugin.js. Code of HorizontalScrollPlugin.js:

```
import Scrollbar from 'smooth-scrollbar'

export default class HorizontalScrollPlugin extends Scrollbar.ScrollbarPlugin {

 transformDelta(delta, fromEvent) {
     if (this.shouldInvertDelta(fromEvent)) {
         return {
            x: delta.y,
            y: delta.y,
         }
     }

     return delta
 }

 shouldInvertDelta(fromEvent) {
    return this.options.events.some((rule) => fromEvent.type.match(rule))
 }

}

HorizontalScrollPlugin.pluginName = 'horizontalScroll'
HorizontalScrollPlugin.defaultOptions = { events: [] }
```

I don't know what to change in this code to allow vertiall scrolling by using the mouse wheel. I tried this `x: delta.x` but it's not working. The rest of the code is here in github `https://github.com/Aqro/gooey-hover-codrops`. Can anyone help?

Comment: It's working for me...

Comment: @code Is x: delta.x working for you when you use the mouse wheel?

Comment: yes, it does work; I'm using Microsoft Edge.